# how can i insert a break line after a ul element - using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to insert a br after the first UL element
I have used both after and insertAfter but it inserts it multiple times.
thanks in advance

```
 <div id="usual1">
<ul class="tabs1">
<li><a href="#Home" class="selected">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#NewPages" class="">NewPages</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="NewPages" style="display: none;">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although you may use this in SharePoint, it really belongs on StackOverflow.com. You'll get more and better answers there as well.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but you'll undoubtedly need to tighten the selector.
`$("ul:first").append("<br/>");`
You haven't given enough specifics for this to be the exact *emphasized text*answer, but hopefully it'll give you the idea.

Comment: Thanks marc since there are a lot of ul's on the page
that won't work so what i did is added a id=header  to the UL like so : <ul class="tabs1" id="header">
then did $("#header").append("<br/>"); 
but that added br immediately after the UL and i want it at the end of </UL>

 <div id="usual1">
<ul class="tabs1">
<li><a href="#Home" class="selected">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#NewPages" class="">NewPages</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="NewPages" style="display: none;">
</div>
</div>

Comment: Patrick, I can't seem to reconcile your example markup above with what you are trying to do. Could you add some indication where in the markup you want the <br/>? *However*, this might be solved better with a CSS margin or the like.